# Webpack build gives me error when i try to use import statement

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, deployment

i'm trying to create a website in js using webpack but whenever i try to import something it breaks and gives me following error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaKE3.png)
my code:
index.js:

```
import './style.css';
import { drawBoard } from './boardUI';
// import { Player } from './player';
// import { Gameboard } from './gameboard';

// drawBoard();
```

boardUI.js:

```
import { Player } from './player';

function drawBoard() {
  let boardGrid = document.getElementById('board_grid');
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    let gridItem = document.createElement('div');
    gridItem.classList.add('grid-item');
    if (i === 100) {
      gridItem.dataset.x = 10;
      gridItem.dataset.y = 10;
    } else {
      gridItem.dataset.x = (i / 10 - Math.floor(i / 10)) * 10;
      gridItem.dataset.y = Math.floor(i / 10) + 1;
    }
    boardGrid.append(gridItem);
  }
}

export { drawBoard };
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "battleship",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/giorgi568/battleship.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/giorgi568/battleship/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/giorgi568/battleship#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.20",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

i used webpack and import statements in the same way before but didn't have such problems.

read some docs and asked chatgpt but nothing

solved! - error was caused by something i was importing in player.js and then boardUI